# Where can I find the b4a .apk on my phone after It gets installed?

Tags: basic4android

I wanted to send the file to a friend via Bluetooth tonight but could not seem to find the apk file on the phone file system, but the icon was installed and in my apps?

Any help would be appreciated. Cheers

Comment: I don't believe you have access to the apk directory on an unrooted device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have access to the install APK files. The APK is available on the desktop under the Objects folder.

Answer (score 2):

If you install an application, the APK file is stored in teh /data/app folder on your system.

You'll need root access to get the apk from there and an file explorer program like root explorer to get there.

Answer (score 0):

You can download an app like app backup and restore to backup this particular application. Download link from play store, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.appbackup

Next u can go to backup, select the app and send, or goto the folders and you will see a folder nameed app backup and restore, from there you can copy to pc or still share to anybody